# WinEdt - Could one compile in a temporary folder without saving the changes in the current file

Tags: editors, winedt

What I want to do is:

1. After press PDFLaTex button, it will save the modified content in a temporary folder.
   For example, if I am editing `C:\math\article.tex`, then it will save the modified
   content to `C:\math\temp\article.tex`. But the modified content is not saved to `C:\math\article.tex`. I would like the keep `C:\math\article.tex` as before, and save it manually when I need. Also, the working window stays still on the current editing document, namely `C:\math\article.tex`.
2. Then it compile the file `C:\math\temp\article.tex`

I have already know how to compile `C:\math\temp\article.tex` when I am working on `C:\math\article.tex`. The remained question is that how to save the modified content to `C:\math\temp\article.tex` , but no to `C:\math\article.tex`. There are macros like "SaveDoc", "SaveAllDoc", "SaveDocAs" and "SaveDocCopyAs". The first two save the contents to the original file (I didn't find parameters for another folders) and the last two will prompt to ask the localization. ( I hope it is always the subfolder `%P\temp` and don't hope the prompt appear).

So is there a way to save the modified content into another file, but not into the original file in WinEdt?

Comment: You may want to pose this question to the winedt discussion forum as well. See http://www.winedt.com/support.html for instructions on how to join this list.